# Date field from Power automate to sharepoint list

Tags: json, sharepoint, power-automate

I have set automate up to parse an email i recieve regularly. The email is system generated through third party software without an API to link directly to SharePoint.

I have used the initialise variable function to parse the HTML from the email and create a new list item.

All fields work, however the Date will not pull through and fails the flow entirely.

I get this error:

> The 'inputs.parameters' of workflow operation 'Create_item' of type 'OpenApiConnection' is not valid. Error details: Input parameter 'item/DateTime' is required to be of type 'String/date'. The runtime value '"25/02/2022"' to be converted doesn't have the expected format 'String/date'.

My column settings in the List are Date & Time field with Date Only set.

[image: list column settings]
[image: Date]
[image: Variables]

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your problem correctly but the format `25/02/2022` is not considered to be a valid ISO 8601 date.

I created a variable called `Date Time String` and stored your date of `25/02/2022`.

To make it valid, you need to convert it and to do that, this expression should do the trick.

`concat(split(variables('Date Time String'), '/')[2], '-', split(variables('Date Time String'), '/')[1], '-', split(variables('Date Time String'), '/')[0])`

It essentially reverses the date into a format that SharePoint will accept.

##### Before

[image: Date Time String]

##### After

[image: Strongly Typed Date Time]

##### New List Item Result

[image: List Item]

Answer (score 0):

You can also parse the date time and then use `formatDateTime` to output the format you want, see below:

```
formatDateTime(parseDateTime(variables('Date Time String'), '', 'dd/MM/yyyy'))
```

Note: In the example above I did not specify a format for formatDateTime (only the parsing step), this will default to outputting the datetime in ISO format which is compatible with SharePoint.